# Secure all urls in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I am using Symfony 2.6.6. And my structure folder

```
ExampleBundle
   Controller
       LoginController.php
       Other1Controller.php
       Other2Controller.php
       ...
```

`LoginController` has `loginAction()` and `loginCheckAction()`
`LoginAction()` will show login form and `loginCheckAction()` for checking that.

I see some tutorial to create `LoginController.php`. After user login by checking I set:

```
$session->set('login', $login);
```

**My purpose is:** All user must login before access all page of my web app.

But my website has many Controller and Action (pages).

**My idea** is: check 'login' session exist in all Action of all Controller and redirect to login action if not exist.

But I think that is too manual. What is the best way to do that with Symfony?

**Update 1:**
After that i try to add some code to my `security.yml` file. It Redirect to login page if user not logged, but it always Redirect to login page. I want if user login (has section 'login') it can access other pages. how to do that thanks

```
# .../security.html
security:
    firewalls:
       ex_login:
            pattern:  ^/ex/login$
            anonymous: ~
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/ex
            form_login:
                check_path: /ex/logincheck
                login_path: /ex/login
            logout:
                path: /ex/logout
                target: /ex
```

**update 2**
Here is my `Login Controller`

```
       loginAction() {
           $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
           if ($session->has('login')) {
               //redirect to home/index
           }else {
               //render login form
           }
       }
       logincheckAction(Request $request) {
           if($request->getMethod()=='POST') {
                // check user input (username && password) in database
                if (ok){
                     $session->set('login', 'true');
                     //redirect to home/index
                }
                else {
                     //redirect to login/index
                }
           }else {
                //redirect to login/index
           }
       }
       logoutAction() {
           //remove login session
           // redirect to login/index
       }
```

Here is my  `Other1Controller.php`

```
indexAction(){
   echo 'page1';
}
```

It always Redirect to login page. After i fill my field and sumbit to login, it still redirect to login page? how can i fix that thanks.

Comment: why you no use security component in symfony?

Comment: read this book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: @ghanbari You mean i'm doing the right way, But using security.yml instead of <b>My idea</b> ? plz give me right example. B/C i have many controller

Comment: book discuss all things that you need that know, but you can install & see this simple project: https://github.com/ghanbari/cyrus, security: https://github.com/ghanbari/cyrus/blob/master/app/config/security.yml conroller: https://github.com/ghanbari/cyrus/blob/master/src/Cyrus/PanelBundle/Controller/LoginController.php

Comment: pattern of ex_login firewall must start with `^` and end with `$` as `pattern:  ^/ex/login$`

Comment: @ghanbari I added that, but i have still problem, plz see my update. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75628/discussion-between-ghanbari-and-dele).

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to protect all urls unless some necessities urls as login and logout

```
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Make sure every user has at least ROLE_USER

Comment: You can use `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` instead of `ROLE_USER` to avoid a must have `ROLE_USER` for each and every user.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the firewall component.
You can, make a automatic redirection when a user need to be logged.

[The official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

Comment: plz give me example for make everyone must login before access all method of Other1 and Other2 Controller thanks